# query function returning value as nil in om.next

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, om, om.next

I am currently trying to learn *om.next*.

This is the code that I have:

```
(ns hlearn.core
  (:require [goog.dom :as gdom]
            [om.next :as om :refer-macros [defui]]
            [om.dom :as dom]
            [sablono.core :as html :refer-macros [html]]))

(enable-console-print!)

(def app-data
  (atom {:user ""
         :main-menu {:selected :home}}))

;; -------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Parsing

(defmulti read om/dispatch)

(defmethod read :selected
  [{:keys [state]} _ _]
  {:value (get-in @state [:main-menu :selected])})

;; -------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Components

(defui MainMenu
  static om/IQuery
  (query [this]
         [:selected])
  Object
  (render [this]
          (let [{:keys [selected]} (om/props this)]
            (println (= selected :home)))))

(def main-menu (om/factory MainMenu))

(defui RootView
  Object
  (render [this]
    (println "Render RootView")
    (main-menu)))

(def reconciler
  (om/reconciler
   {:state  app-data
    :parser (om/parser {:read read})}))

(om/add-root! reconciler
  RootView (gdom/getElement "app"))
```

My goal here is that the component `MainMenu` has to write `true` on the console (currently writes `false`).

Since the read function should return `{:value :home}` (value on the app-state), therefore `(= selected :home)` should be true.

In practice, `MainMenu` writes `false` on the console, because `selected` has the value `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the `RootView` component that is rendered on `(om/add-root!)` must provide the query for all the application.

In this case `RootView` must provide a query as well, and pass the `selected` key to the `MainMenu` component.

```
(def app-data
  (atom {:user ""
         :menu {:selected :home}}))

(defui RootView
  static om/IQuery
  (query [this]
    `[{:menu (om/get-query MainMenu)}])
  Object
  (render [this]
    (let [{:keys [menu]} (om/props this)]
      (println "Render RootView")
      (main-menu menu))))
```

Also, the reader function dispatches on the `:menu` key, instead of the `:selected` key.

```
(defmethod read :menu
  [{:keys [state]} _ _]
  {:value (get-in @state [:menu])})
```

The rest of the code remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

In `om.next`, all queries have to compose to the root component, as you discovered. The root component is assigned its `props` based on what the `read` function returns when it processes the root query.

If any subcomponents have a query, the props requested by that query should be passed down as the first argument the subcomponent's factory method. This was the second piece you were missing.

There isn't currently any warning or error in Om if you query for something in a subcomponent that isn't ultimately passed down by its parent. So you end up destructuring a `nil` value for the key in the subcomponent if you forget to pass down props.